# Combine 2 string columns in pandas with different conditions in both columns with another condition within

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following data frame, there are other categories besides `cat1` but I only want to make a change to the part of the dataframe where the category is `cat1`.

```
name   short code     category
thyrax thx   thxar.po cat1
gha    gh    gh.cd    cat1
play   pl    pl.v     cat1
xxdx   xd    xda.v    cat1
......
```

For cases where everything after the `.` in the code column is anything besides `.cd`, I want the short column to take what's in the short column + what is after the `.` in the `code` column and become something like `thx.po`, but in cases where there is a `cd`, I want it to become `.cn`. I want the output to look like this,

```
name   short    code     category
thyrax thx.po   thxar.po cat1
gha    gh.cn    gh.cd    cat1
play   pl.v     pl.v     cat1
xxdx   xd.v     xda.v    cat1
......
```

I don't know how to add a condition that `IF` the category is `cat1`  and the code after the `.` is `.cd`, make it into `short` + what's after the `.` +cn.

I want the same condition for everything unless what is after the `.` to be copied, but if what is after the `.` is a `.cn`, I want it to be a `.cd`. What is the best way to do it?

I have gotten this code so far,

```
df['short'] = (df['short'].add("."+df['code'].str.split(".").str[-1]).where(df['category'].eq("cat1"),df['short']))
```

But I can't figure out how to add the condition where if in the code column, what appears after the `.` is `.cd` and to have something different happen.

So basically my conditions are this,

firstly, category must be `cat1`,

then take what is in the short column and merge it with what is after the `.` in the code column.

If what is after the `.` in the code column is `cd`, make it into `cn`.

Comment: Have you considered using apply with a custom function, and putting all the condition logic there?

Comment: no I have no idea how to do that, could you point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['short'] = df['short'].astype(str) + np.where(df['category'].eq('cat1'), df['code'].astype(str).str.extract('(\..+)')[0].replace('.cd', '.cn'), '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     name   short      code category
0  thyrax  thx.po  thxar.po     cat1
1     gha      gh     gh.cd     cat2
2     gha   gh.cn     gh.cd     cat1
3    play    pl.v      pl.v     cat1
4    xxdx      xd     xda.v     cat2
5    xxdx      xd     xda.v     cat2
6    xxdx    xd.v     xda.v     cat1
```

(I added some dummy rows in the above data to demonstrate that it works with the right category, `cat1`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mask = df['category'] == 'cat1'
df.loc[mask, 'short'] += '.' + df.loc[mask, 'code'] \
                                 .str.split('.').str[1].replace({'cd': 'cn'})
print(df)

# Output:
     name   short      code category
0  thyrax  thx.po  thxar.po     cat1
1     gha   gh.cd     gh.cd     cat1
2    play    pl.v      pl.v     cat1
3    xxdx    xd.v     xda.v     cat1
```

Comment: what about the case where what is after the `.` is `cd`?, it needs to be converted in that case into `.cn`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def custom_apply_function(row):
    if row['category'] != 'cat1':
        return row.short
    code_after_dot = row.code.split('.')[1]
    if code_after_dot == 'cd':
        code_after_dot = 'cn'
    new_short = row.short + '.' + code_after_dot
    return new_short

df.apply(axis=1, func=custom_apply_function)
```

returns

```
0    thx.po
1     gh.cn
2      pl.v
3      xd.v
```

Other answers in this thread are certainly faster due to vectorisation. In case you'd like to complicate the conditions further though, I would go with the more explicit version.